# Looking for a number in a group (array)

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to perform a group conditional statement?

For example, I have a process which returns random numbers from an array (x) which I want to compare to the first 100 prime numbers.

Is there a function or method available by which I could do:

```
if (x in first_100_prime_numbers)
    ...
```

Comment: From your past questions, I assume this is for Objective-C.  Xcode is just the IDE.

Comment: You could stick the first 100 prime numbers into an NSHashTable, then call containsObject on it to see if a number is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Almo already said in a comment, many collection classes in Cocoa have a `containsObject:` method that you can use for this purpose. Note that performing `containsObject:` on an array will probably be much slower (especially when the array is large) than on a set or hash table as the method has to iterate over every item in the array until it finds a match.